# Wikitude Cordova Plugin - Handle Android and iOS errors

Tags: wikitude, wikitude-sdk

Wikitude Cordova Plugin is used to create our own augmented reality in our cordova based apps. But after adding the plugin and following the official examples the app fails,

- In android, app.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported fails with the error,

  > `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference`
- In iOS, the app crashes with the error,

  > `This app has crashed because
  >   it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
  >   description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an
  >   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
  >   user how the app uses this data.`

Are there any work arounds. How to solve the Android and iOS issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Wikitude Cordova Plugin

[Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/) is an Augmented Reality engine. And [Wikitude Cordova Plugin](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/gettingstartedphonegap.html#getting-started-cordova-plugin) is an Augmented Reality SDK for Cordova to embed augmented reality experiences into your PhoneGap and Cordova based app.

Note: This document holds good for `com.wikitude.phonegap.wikitudeplugin` **v 6.1.0**. *Other versions are not tested*.

#### 1. Add the plugin to your app

Open a console and go to your project directory and run the cordova plugin add command

`$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-cordova-plugin.git`

This will add the plugin to your application.

Run `cordova prepare` to make the the project ready to build as per ***config.xml***

#### 2. Enter Wikitude license Key

Go to [License Page](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/licenses) and download your personal license key for the Wikitude SDK.

To use the Wikitude Cordova Plugin with a certain license key, use the `this._sdkKey` property defined in ***WikitudePlugin.js*** line ***13***.

> plugins\com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin\www\WikitudePlugin.js

#### 3. Android: Handle Wikitude plugin error

In android, app.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported may fail with the error,

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

Handle the error by adding a null check to an array in ***WikitudePlugin.java***

> plugins\com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin\src\android\WikitudePlugin.java

***line 755:*** add a null check `if(jsonArray != null){}` to `for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {}`

#### 4. Update platforms

Run the below commands to update the platforms with the changes made in the Wikitude Plugin. It will remove and add the platforms back.

`cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios`

#### 5. iOS: Allow CameraUsage

In iOS, the app may crash with the error,

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Use [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) to modify the app's plist file.

Run the following command from Mac

`$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :NSCameraUsageDescription string 'Access to the camera is needed to display augmented reality content on top of your camera image.'" "platforms/ios/"${PROJECT_NAME}"/"${PROJECT_NAME}"-Info.plist"`

Or you can manually add the below entry into `platforms/ios/"${PROJECT_NAME}"/"${PROJECT_NAME}"-Info.plist`

> NSCameraUsageDescription
>   Access to the camera is needed to display augmented reality content on top of your camera image.

#### 6. Create your own augmented reality experience

Steps to Create your own augmented reality experience can be found in [Wikitude SDK Cordova documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/setupguidecordovacli.html#using-the-wikitude-plugin-to-create-your-own-augmented-reality-experience).

Code Examples for what can be done using the Wikitude SDK can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples). Also the example Wikitude Cordova Plugin can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-cordova-plugin-samples).

For `isDeviceSupported` function `requiredFeatures` is optional. But without providing it the App won't work for iOS. So make sure you provide it.

`requiredFeatures: [ "2d_tracking", "geo" ],
...
app.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(app.onDeviceSupported, app.onDeviceNotSupported, app.requiredFeatures);`

#### 7. Build project

Run the following commands to build the project to specific platforms

`cordova build android
cordova build ios`

For more details on building the apps refer the [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) [documentions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html), [Android Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) and [iOS Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/)

Note: #7 is needed for every build. The remaining steps are required only during initial setup.

#### Supported devices

Refer: https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/supporteddevices.html

Android device requirements:

- Android 4.0.3+
- Compass
- Accelerometer
- High resolution devices (hdpi)
- Rear-facing camera
- [OpenGL 2.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)
- Devices with a quad-core CPU or higher

Supported iOS devices:

- iPhone 5 or newer
- iPad (4th gen) or newer
- iPod Touch (6th gen) or newer

#### Reference

Wikitude Cordova Plugin:    https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/

#### Note:

Step#3 solves the Android issue and Step#5 solves the iOS issue.

Following [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)